# CSS: Modal window scroll the body but not the title when there isn't enough room

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog, flexbox, css-position

I am trying to use CSS to make a Modal window. I want it to be just large enough to fit the content, however, when there is not enough room on the screen, I want a scroll bar to appear in the body of the modal window, leaving its Title and button row in view at all times. How do I achieve this?

I can either have the scroll appear correctly when there is not enough room, but then the modal is way too big when the screen size is large,
or 
I can have the modal sized correctly, but the scroll bar doesn't show up.

Here is a jsfiddle with my attempt. What am I doing wrong?
https://jsfiddle.net/7Lmj0eoj/1/

Also, here is the same source code pasted below:

CSS:

```
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.modalBackground {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.modalWindow {
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px #999;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: auto;
  left: 50%;
  right: auto;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 350px;

  /*
  if you enable these two lines, the scroll bar appears in the right place,
  but it doesn't get sized correctly when there is enough space to fit the whole thing.
  max-height: calc(100vh - 20px);
  height: 100%
  */

  overflow-y: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}    

.modalWindow .title {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 10px 20px;
}

.modalWindow .body {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;

}

.modalWindow .actions {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin: 10px 20px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="modalBackground">
  <div class="modalWindow">
    <div class="title">Modal Title</div>
    <div class="body">
      <p>
        This is the body of the modal window and the only part that should scroll when there is not enough space to fit on the screen. The title and the button section should be outside of the scrollable area.
      </p>
      <p>
      When there is room to fit the whole content of the dialog, it should not be larger than it has to be. In other words, the modal height should be just big enough to fit the content and when there is no room, a scrollbar should appear on the .body div tag.
      </p>
      <p>How can I make this work? Thank you.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
      <button type="button">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you specify the height of the modal body, you can allow the body of the modal to scroll with he overflow property:

```
.modalWindow .body{
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Here's a great resource on CSS scroll https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

**EDIT:**

Based on your comment, it may be worth using media queries to ONLY introduce scroll if the screen height is under a predetermined value.

For example:

```
@media screen and (max-height: 700px) {
    .modalWindow .body{
      height: 200px;
      overflow-y: scroll;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't know the height of the body ahead of time. The content of the .body could be tall or short and I only want it to scroll when it doesn't fit on the screen.

Comment: In that case, you could use max-height instead of height?

Comment: Well, no because there is no max-height. The max height is that it has to fit on the screen.

Comment: Agree with @TidyDev. I'd probably use overflow-y instead of overflow. Just in case.

Comment: Can you guys get a working example on jsfiddle. It has to be a generic solution that works for any length of content in the body?

Comment: @DerekNolan is correct, overflow-y would be better than just overflow.

Comment: @aherriot If you want to dynamically set the height it would probably be easiest to use a little JavaScript/ jQuery.

Comment: Surely is it possible to get a modal window to take just enough space when there is room, and a scroll bar in just the right area when there isn't without introduction JavaScript. I am just not sure how.

Comment: @aherriot Setting the max-height of ModalWindow to 100%.

Comment: @DerekNolan Thank you so much for your suggestions, however that still doesn't address the fundamental problem that I stated in the question: "I can either have the scroll appear correctly when there is not enough room, but then the modal is way too big when the screen size is large, or I can have the modal sized correctly, but the scroll bar doesn't show up."

Comment: @aherriot you could use a media query that only kicks in below a specific height, i've amended my answer to reflect this.